# Razor @Html.ActionLink adds current id to path - why?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working through the same code in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-an-instructors-page

I am confused why the following (in the view that is from the Instructors controller)
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { courseID = item.CourseID })

produces the link:
https/localhost:44325/Instructors/Index/4?courseID=1050

Why does it give the number 4?
It is correct. I have selected the instructor number 4.
I get the Instructors is the controller, but how did it know to include 4 (which is the id in the route)

Comment: Can you show as the whole view starting from @model

Comment: model ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.InstructorIndexData
if (Model.Courses != null)
{
 <h3>Courses Taught by Selected Instructor</h3>
 <table class="table">
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Number</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Department</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model.Courses)
  {
   string selectedRow = "";
   if (item.CourseID == (int?)ViewData["CoursEId"])
    selectedRow = "bg-success";
   <tr class="@selectedRow">
    <td>
     @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { courseID = item.CourseID });

Comment: sorry for that large comment - I don't know how to add an attachment - you can go to the link in the original question and it will show the code in a nicer format

Answer (score 0):

It is because you click `<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="xxx">Select</a>` first.And it will change the url link of second 'Select'.
Here is a demo:

Index:

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="1">Select</a>
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { courseID = 1 })
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it round trips between clicks.  I would like to see something in the documentation stating this behavior.  I had thought actionLink would build the href, but it seems like it does a replace on the href and the route id comes for a ride.

Comment: what tool did you use to make such a cool post?  (and how did you post that at stackoverflow - i only know how to post text)

Comment: You can post gif at stackoverflow.This is a gif,just add it like adding an image.

Answer (score 0):

Model binding will look at each parameter in the action method and set it if possible.  In this case, the id is part of the route and that is why it is bound.

thanks for those who left answers - I appreciate the support